# Scala Option: Usage of unless with getOrElse

Tags: scala, scala-option

I have an Option of string, say O, which can be empty. And there is a condition, say cond. My requirement is to construct Option of the value inside O if cond is true, else None.
I do this:

```
Option.unless(cond)(o.getOrElse(None))
```

Is this a correct functional way of doing it? Or there can be a better/cleaner/easy to understand way?

Comment: `o.filter(_ => cond)` ? Or if you have **cats** `o.whenA(cond)`

Comment: Thanks. Seems lot to learn in Scala.

Comment: There's a lot of ways to do things in Scala, and it's generally OK to not know every bit right away.

Comment: To add to @LeviRamsey, it's really functional programming in general that there is a lot to learn, Scala is just a tool for doing FP. You would likely perform nearly the same thing in Haskell or even Java using their `Optional`. Tough to know everything about FP, I admittedly don't. It does take time, just keep chipping away at it.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, the answer is to use `filter`:

```
o.filter(_ => cond)
```

The condition in a `filter` does not have to use the value that is passed to it, but can be any expression that returns a Boolean.